# Automorphism on $\mathbb{Q}_p$

Tags: p-adic-number-theory

How many automorphism are there in the field of $p$-adic?

% I suspect that there's only one automorphism, the Identity. But I stuck with the continuously of the automorphism in $\mathbb{Q}_p$.

Comment: can you gimme a hint for the continuity?
thanks

Comment: I did. In an answer of the duplicate. Check it out!

Comment: Eh?okay, 
*I missed that.
Thanks.